# Multiple Objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object, npm

I have a weird looking object that I would like to turn into an object with multiple objects. (what I mean by multiple objects in nested objects) The current object looks like this:

```
{
  'test.txt': "This is a test\r\n\r\nI hope  it'll work",
  'testy.js': 'console.log("thonk");\r\n',
  'thonk\\i swear\\egg.txt': 'am going to be happy?',    
  'thonk\\pls work.txt': 'dasdas'
}
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
{
  "test.txt": "This is a test\r\n\r\nI hope it'll work",
  "testy.js": "console.log('thonk');\r\n",
  "thonk": {
    "I swear": { 
        "egg.txt": "am going to be happy?" 
     },
    "pls work.txt": "dasdas"
  }
}
```

Edit:
here's what my code is (if u need it):

```
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");
var walk = function (dir, done) {
  var results = [];
  fs.readdir(dir, function (err, list) {
    if (err) return done(err);
    var i = 0;
    (function next() {
      var file = list[i++];
      if (!file) return done(null, results);
      file = path.resolve(dir, file);
      fs.stat(file, function (err, stat) {
        if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
          walk(file, function (err, res) {
            results = results.concat(res);
            next();
          });
        } else {
          results.push(file);
          next();
        }
      });
    })();
  });
};

var root = "test";
var data = {};

walk("test", function (err, results) {
  if (err) throw err;

  for (i in results) {
    data[
      results[i].replace(__dirname + "\\" + root + "\\", "")
    ] = fs.readFileSync(results[i], "utf8");
  }

  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: The thing that creates the nested object is `\\` ? Should we use that to create nested objects ?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Yes! sorry I didn't  know what you meant

Comment: they're seperated by \\

Comment: Maybe every double slash, create an object?

Comment: can you please rewrite and format the desired output? it seems weird.

Comment: yes - using ‘\\’ as our delimiter we can basically do as Karma suggests. Grepping through this tree and using recursively keep tearing down the new “result object” and rebuilding it until we reach the end. Each pass through would effectively add one new object to its object graph until we complete. I’m typing this on my phone currently, but I could throw together a clean(ish) example of what I’m thinking later or tomorrow if you’d like, and if no one else beats me to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by combining [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) as follows:

```js
const source = {
  'test.txt': "This is a test\r\n\r\nI hope  it'll work",
  'testy.js': 'console.log("thonk");\r\n',
  'thonk\\i swear\\egg.txt': 'am going to be happy?',
  'thonk\\pls work.txt': 'dasdas'
}

const result = Object.keys(source).reduce((target, k) => {
  const keys = k.split('\\');
  if (keys.length == 1) {
    target[k] = source[k];
  } else {
    const nestedObj = target[keys[0]] || {};
    keys.slice(1).reduce((o, nestedKey, i) => {
      const value = i < keys.length -2 ? {} : source[k];      
      o[nestedKey] = value;
      return value;
    }, nestedObj);
    target[keys[0]] = nestedObj;
  }
  return target;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

So you should create new object, then go through each element, combining items that you need and placing them to a new one.

Comment: I'm confused how you would do that, can you please create an example?